# JSON parsing in android

Tags: android, json

My `JSON` response like this, every time id came different,

```
{
    "all_user_engagements": {
        "fa0e7579": {
            "shared_stats": {
                "em": {
                    "share": true
                }
            }
        },
        "5c14558e": {
            "shared_stats": {
                "tw": {
                    "sharedpost_lclick": true,
                    "share": true
                },
                "ln": {
                    "share": true
                },
                "fb": {
                    "share": true
                },
                "wa": {
                    "share": true
                },
                "em": {
                    "share": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to get this kind of `object` in android? I am trying this code to get `JSONObject`.

```
    JSONObject mAllUserJsonObject =   parentObject.getJsonobject("all_user_engagements");
```

Comment: Your json is invalid. Please check it once.

Comment: @subrahmanyamboyapati Nope . I checked it .Json valid

Comment: #Hitesh paste your json here http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: now he updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the `JSON` by iterating through it, something like below:

```
Iterator<String> keysIterator = mAllUserJsonObject.keys();
while (keysIterator.hasNext()) 
{
    String keyStr = (String)keysIterator.next(); // This would be "fa0e7579" or "5c14558e"
    JSONObject valueObject = mAllUserJsonObject.getJSONObject(keyStr);
}
```

And I am hoping you can parse `valueObject` as the keys are known to you.

Answer (score 0):

try using HashMap and get the key and Values.

Though i am not a fan of this concept but then you can keep a string check and do whatever operation you want to perform on the keys.

```
Map<String, Object> retMap = new Gson().fromJson(
    jsonString, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType()
);
```

Answer (score -2):

User GSON parser and create root model for all_user_engagements.